# (8)Exec format error: exec of ' ' failed - CentOS

Tags: python, linux

I am using a CentOS VM from Backspace with LAMP installed. 
I have a python script I want to run from the CGI-BIN. 
I have browsed to the path on my browser and I get an 500 server error. 
Assured, this is the first time I ever used CentOS and python but I understand pretty well. but this has really got me. 
I get this error :

```
[Tue Nov 04 12:46:07 2014] [error] [client 86.2.110.133] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/payment-test.cgi' failed
[Tue Nov 04 12:46:07 2014] [error] [client 86.2.110.133] Premature end of script headers: payment-test.cgi
```

Here is my script :

```
import sys
import json
import cgi
import cgitb
import stripe

#2
cgitb.enable()

print 'Content-Type: text/json'
print

#3
stripe.api_key = ''
#4
json_data = sys.stdin.read()
json_dict = json.loads(json_data)

#5
stripeAmount = json_dict['stripeAmount']
stripeCurrency = json_dict['stripeCurrency']
stripeToken = json_dict['stripeToken']
stripeDescription = json_dict['stripeDescription']

#6
json_response = stripe.Charge.create(amount=stripeAmount, currency=stripeCurrency, card=stripeToken, description=stripeDescription)

print json_response
```

Is it because there is no header pointing to my Python files ? If so where are they ? 
Please help I am so lost.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [hashbang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script) at the top.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import cgi
...
```

Comment: yup thats fine, but what should be in /usr/bin/env ?

Comment: I don't have an env folder in my bin folder

Comment: It also really MUST be on the very FIRST line.   As I found out, having a blank line above it gives a big error also.